# insert into table with composite primary key columns only

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I try to run an insert statement (via MySQLdb-python) like this:

```
insert into LinkTable1ToTable2 (site_id, customer_id) values ('xyz-c1', '123');
```

Only to get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'xyz-c1-123' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

It's a linking table (intermediate table) that links two other tables that have many-to-many relationship. The table consists of two columns that form a composite primary key and looks like this:

```
    site_id | customer_id
   ---------------------
    xyz-a1  | 121
    xyz-b1  | 122
```

The table schema is:

```
 Field,        Type,        Null,     Key,    Default,    Extra
'site_id',     'char(40)',  'NO',    'PRI',    '',        ''
'customer_id',  'int(11)',   'NO',    'PRI',    '0',       ''
```

After many hours of searching on the Internet and stackoverflow, the only thing I came up with is some flimsy:

```
insert ignore into LinkTable1ToTable2 (site_id, customer_id) values ('xyz-c1', '123')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE site_id=values(site_id), customer_id=values(customer_id);
```

which only returns:

```
0 row(s) affected
```

and I feel a bit lost...

I need an insert statement that inserts a pair of site_id and customer_id into the table (see the statement in the beginning of the question, please).

Can anyone help?

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're trying to insert a string ('123' is a string) into a column that is defined as an integer column. As a result, MySQL will default to 0 for that column, which it's probably doing both times, hence the duplicate rows.

Comment: Which types are the columns in `LinkTable1ToTable2` ? What is PK in this table?

Comment: @Tom H: hmm, valid suggestion. Thnx.

Comment: If that solves your problem, please be sure to let us know so that the question can be marked as closed.

Comment: I tried "insert into LinkTable1ToTable2 (site_id, customer_id) values ('xyz-c1', 123);" and got: Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`LinkTable1ToTable2`, CONSTRAINT `LinkTable1ToTable2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `Sites` (`site_id`))

Comment: I solved it. Thanks! I had two problems at a time :) One, as mentioned by Tom - wrong type of the filed, the second was the fact that I am using non-existent site_id... I pulled that site_id from an updated table programmatically (with Python), but the actual Sites table doesn't have it yet - hence foreign key constraint error.